# Single expression containing the same pattern multiple times

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I have an expression like this `Exp[-x^2]^(Log[a+3])*Sin[x]*y^(x)*Sin[Cos[b]]`, and I want to match the pattern `base_^pwr_*Sin[arg_]` s.t

```
Exp[-x^2]^(Log[a+3])*Sin[x]*y^(x)*Sin[Cos[b]] /. base_^pwr_*Sin[arg_]-> {base,pwr, arg}
```

will evaluate a list of lists where each sublist is one of the matched patters of the form `{base,pwr, arg}`.

However, when I run this code, I get
$$\left\{e^{-x^{2}} y^{x} \sin [\cos [b]], y^{x} \log [3+a] \sin [\cos [b]], x y^{x} \sin [\cos [b]]\right\}$$
which doesn't make any sense.

Ideally, I would like to get something like

```
{{e^{-x^{2}}, Log[3+a], x}, {y,x, Cos[b]}, {e^{-x^{2}}, Log[3+a], Cos[b]}, {y,x,x}}
```

Why am I getting this result and how can match check for multiple matchings of the same pattern in a single expression.

Comment: In these cases I always start my analysis by looking at the `InputForm` of your original expression.

Comment: Dear @MarcoB, do you mean something like `expr1 = Exp[x^2]^(Log[a+3])*Sin[x]*y^(x)*Sin[Cos[b]]; InputForm[expr1]` ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `Cases` if you just want to find subexpressions matching a certain pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *is* a case for [`ReplaceList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceList.html):

```
expr = Exp[-x^2]^(Log[a + 3]) Sin[x] y^(x)  Sin[Cos[b]]; 

pattern = ___ base_^pwr_ Sin[arg_] :> {base, pwr, arg};

ReplaceList[expr, pattern]
```

> ```
> {{E^-x^2, Log[3 + a], x}, 
>  {E^-x^2, Log[3 + a], Cos[b]},
>  {y, x, x},
>  {y,  x, Cos[b]}}
> ```

This also works:

```
Map[Flatten] @ Tuples @ Values @
  GroupBy[List @@ expr, Head, ReplaceAll[ {Sin[x_] :> x, Power[a_, b_] :> {a, b}}]]
```

> same result

And this:

```
DeleteDuplicates @ SequenceCases[List @@ expr, 
  {OrderlessPatternSequence[Power[a_, b_], Sin[c_], ___]} :> {a, b, c}, 
  Overlaps -> All]
```

> same result

Answer (score 3):

This is only a partial answer to explain the result that you see.

```
expr1 = Exp[-x^2]^(Log[a + 3])*Sin[x]*y^(x)*Sin[Cos[b]];

expr1 /. base_^pwr_*Sin[arg_] -> {base, pwr, arg}

(* {E^-x^2 y^x Sin[Cos[b]], y^x Log[3 + a] Sin[Cos[b]], x y^x Sin[Cos[b]]} *)
```

The pattern matched `(E^(-x^2))^(Log[3+a])* Sin[x]` and replaced it with the list `{E^(-x^2), Log[3+a], x}` This gave

```
{E^(-x^2), Log[3 + a], x}*y^x*Sin[Cos[b]]

(* {E^-x^2 y^x Sin[Cos[b]], y^x Log[3 + a] Sin[Cos[b]], x y^x Sin[Cos[b]]} *)
```

If you want it to continue until there are no more matches you would need to use [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html)

```
expr1 //. base_^pwr_*Sin[arg_] -> {base, pwr, arg}

(* {{E y^x, -x^2 y^x, y^x Cos[b]}, {y Log[3 + a], x Log[3 + a], 
  Cos[b] Log[3 + a]}, {x y, x^2, x Cos[b]}} *)
```

I would guess that instead you might want to use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html); however, you have not clearly defined what your desired result should be. And you should be looking at the [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of `expr1`

Comment: Dear Bob, see my edit please.